# Accelerometer Interrupt Meaning - Wakeup Function

Tags: sensors, interrupt, accelerometer, sleep

I am working with an LSM9DS1 IMU, and now specifically trying to program a wakeup feature into the system. My idea is to set the accelerometer at the lowest possible read rate, then when the accelerometer value exceeds a predefined level, to have the system wake up.

When programming the sensor, there is a register called INT_GEN_CFG_XL that has a "6-Direction detection for interrupt." I was wondering what this means. Does this perhaps calculate the magnitude of acceleration, and see if that goes above a predefined value? I can see the other interrupt generators are for 1-direction of each of the three axes, but I can't interrupt this one.

Here is a link to the [device datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00103319.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The INT_GEN_CFG_XL 6-Direction detection interrupt apparently is aimed at detecting change of direction of travel, rather than an axis-combined acceleration level.

See the [LSM303](https://forum.pololu.com/t/design-qs-lsm303-sleep-to-wakeup-and-inertial-interrupts/4900/2) discussion at Polulu.com.  That page includes a link to [App Note CD00290365.pdf](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/CD00290365.pdf) for the LIS3DH.  Here is what that app note says, on page 27:

> There are two possible configurations for the 6D direction function:
>
> > • 6D movement recognition: In this configuration the interrupt is generated when the device moves from a direction (known or unknown) to a different known direction. ...
> >     •  6D position recognition: In this configuration the interrupt is generated when the device is stable in a known direction. ...

With the LSM9DS1 that you are using, you can leave OR enabled, set separate X,Y,Z threshholds in INT_GEN_THS_X_XL, INT_GEN_THS_Y_XL, INT_GEN_THS_Z_XL, and set the “Enable interrupt generation on accelerometer's X axis high event” (sim. for Y and Z) bits in the INT_GEN_CFG_XL register.